# Guava thread management when pre-loading and refreshing cache entries

Tags: java, caching, guava

We want to use guava cache for caching third party data to have better response times. The cache needs to be pre-loaded by making a sequence of api calls (~ 4000 api calls are to be made). The api response contains the cache key and its value. These api calls need to be made in parallel from multiple threads (i.e. thread pool) to speed up the cache loading. *Each cache entry* would have an expiry time. This can be set using expireAfterAccess() call. 
After a cache entry expires, it needs to be refreshed automatically in the background. Also there should be a way (api) through which we can stop this background cache refresh so that we do not keep making api calls endlessly. We will call this api once we stop getting user requests after a configured time interval.

Is it possible to delegate the thread management for cache loading and refresh to guava? i.e. Given the api call, the code to map the json response to java object and cache key-value design, can guava perform the pre-loading and refresh on its own?

Thanks.

Comment: AFIAK there is no refreshing capabilities in Guava. Lightweight in process cache alternatives that have this feature would be Caffeine or [cache2k](https://cache2k.org). Here is a recent discussion about the topic: https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine/issues/261. Please modify your question, in case you accept an alternative suggestion to Guava.

Comment: @cruftex - Thanks for the comment. Have you verified this in the latest version (v26) and on the upcoming roadmap? There is no way for performing auto-refresh?

Comment: Interesting. I double checked and actually I was wrong. Guava has automatic refreshing.

Answer (score 1):

Automatic refreshing in Guava can be enabled via [CacheBuilder.refreshAfterWrite()](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.html#refreshAfterWrite-java.time.Duration-). The relevant semantics are described as:

> Specifies that active entries are eligible for automatic refresh once
>   a fixed duration has elapsed after the entry's creation, or the most
>   recent replacement of its value. [ ... ] Currently automatic refreshes
>   are performed when the first stale request for an entry occurs.

When overriding the method `CacheLoader.reload()` you can use a thread pool to load values asynchronously.

The problem with this behavior is that you always have a few reads of stale values, before the new value has been loaded, if it succeeds. An alternative cache implementation, like [cache2k](https://cache2k.org) starts the refreshing immediately after the duration. The latter approach leads to more recent data, but possibly more needless reads. See some recent discussion about that here: https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine/issues/261

Comment: Reading stale values till the new values are getting loaded is acceptable to our use-case. The refreshAfterWrite() method does help in auto-refreshing but I am not sure if the default implementation does it in background. In the test that I wrote [here](https://pastebin.com/SV6ns38M) it seems that the main thread is doing the refresh. Here's the [output](https://pastebin.com/Z5gCiWLm). Notice the last assert which indicates that the auto-refresh for the second entry is triggered after the sleep call in the main thread finishes. Thoughts?

Comment: Where is the code? Although I am not an expert with Google Guava or Caffeine, which has similar semantics, I assume that the first stale read is triggering the loader.

Comment: Since the general question is answered, maybe its a good idea to add a follow-up question with your actual code. Usually the Google guys help out as well.

Comment: Here's the code - https://pastebin.com/SV6ns38M and here's the output - https://pastebin.com/Z5gCiWLm